# settings.py, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, settings

I'm getting this error message when trying to migrate:

```
line 82, in <module>
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

line 82 is the 4th line here:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

here's all the code for the settings.py file (i took out the secret key):

```
"""
Django settings for ProTwo project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'appTwo'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProTwo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProTwo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

any idea? what i don't understand is that I never touched line 82, thats the code that was in the file. The code that I added was at the top:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

then in TEMPLATES, I added:

```
'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
```

finally in INSTALLED_APPS, I added:

```
'appTwo'
```

thnx

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to divide a string by string.
To join two parts of a path do this:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
```

Comment: Would I put that at the top under # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.? This is where I put it but am still getting the same error message:                      " line 85, in <module>
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'"

Comment: @go2nirvana Can Youi Answer This:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213757/how-to-set-base-dir-for-the-production-settings-in-django-3-1-4

Answer (score 7):

replace line 80 with this:

```py
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```

it worked on my project hope it will work for you too

Answer (score 3):

I think you rewrite your BASE_DIR code. Your code should be

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Comment: Can Youi Answer This:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213757/how-to-set-base-dir-for-the-production-settings-in-django-3-1-4

Answer (score 0):

thank you go2nirvanna, yours & another post which said:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

made it work!

here's the post:
[SQLite 3 Database with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762878/sqlite-3-database-with-django)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this error, doing this solved it.
Instead of `BASE_DIR / 'object'` write it as `BASE_DIR , 'object'`

Reference: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32538

Answer (score 0):

```
DB_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent.parent

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': DB_PATH / 'db/db.sqlite3',
}
```

}

My file directory was home/user/db so what I did was, moved to the parent of parent of my current directory of Django project and concatenated 'db/' with 'db.sqlite3'. it worked

Answer (score 0):

Replace your STATIC_ROOT with this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: your answer is off topic. The question owner did  not ask for `STATIC_ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

#I solved this error through changing BASE_DIR in settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when attempting to start my Django development server.

[image]

This error typically occurs in Python when you attempt to perform the division operation (/) between incompatible types. In this case, it seems that you're trying to use the division operator (/) with two string operands, which Python does not support for string concatenation or path manipulation.

I edited the settings.py file by commenting out the "import os" line and instead used 'from pathlib import Path', as shown in the screenshot below:

In addition, the purpose of the line as BASE_DIR = Path(`__file__`).resolve().parent.parent is to define a variable called BASE_DIR that represents the base directory of the Django project. This is commonly used in Django projects to create absolute paths to various resources like templates, static files, and databases.

By obtaining the parent directory of the current file (the settings file) twice, it effectively moves two levels up in the directory hierarchy, landing in the root directory of the Django project.

[image]

Additionally, I edited TEMPLATES configuration in the settings.py file and added the "BASE_DIR / 'templates'". This line specifically sets the directory or directories where Django will look for template files.

[image]

Subsequent to the modifications, the log entries indicate that there were two successful GET requests for the '/firstTemplate/' URL path, both returning a response with a status code of 200 and a response size of 136 bytes. This indicates that the functionality is now operational.

[image]