# How to set BASE_DIR for the Production Settings in Django 3.1.4?

Tags: django

**This is my folder structure.**

[image]

I want to set BASE_DIR in production.py file.

**In older version of Django this is how we used to set the BASE_DIR:**

From:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

To:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

**But in latest version of Django we "Path" to set BASE_DIR**

From:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

To:

```
???
```

**So how to set BASE_DIR for above folder structure**

Answer (score 3):

It should be

`BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent`

You can think of `.parent` as `os.path.dirname`, it has the same effect,
in older versions you used `dirname` 3 times, you can replace it with 3 `.parent`
while using `pathlib.Path` object.