# Why getting settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.?

Tags: python, django

I have not written so much line just created a new database in setting.py and routers file in django project.
After this run following command in shell and every this goes well and a new file with name auth_db.db.sqlite3 create.

```
python manage.py migrate --database=auth_db
```

**and**

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\project\assignment>python manage.py createsuperuser --database=auth_db
Username (leave blank to use 'admin'): admin
Email address: admin@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.
```

**setting.py:-**

```
"""
Django settings for assignment project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pg_xyl$21ofn1f5n*%vaymeniyubo3h^a2jmy&b$=83!gs+ni%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'assignment.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'assignment.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'auth_db.db.sqlite3',
    },
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.db_routers.AuthRouter']
```

But when i tried to login in admin panel after running command `python manage.py runserver` i get error:

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: Check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31762928/16236820)

Comment: There even is a link in your settings file to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases: "The **DATABASES** setting must configure a **default** database; any number of additional databases may also be specified.". You didn't configure a default database.