# How to connect SQLlite to a project in Django (not an app)

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models, makemigrations

While creating the project I didn't create an app and did everything in the base project. Now I am trying to connect database to my base project(not the app)

I tried 'python manage.py makemigrations' but its showing "No changes detected".

I even tried adding my project to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and then trying 'python manage.py makemigrations ' but it is showing an error " for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable "

I have created two models

```
from django.db import models

class studentlogin(models.Model):
stu_name = 
models.CharField(max_length=30,default='',null=False)
stu_email = 
models.EmailField(max_length=20,default='',null=False)
stu_password = 
models.SlugField(max_length=15,default='',null=False) 


class facultylogin():
fac_name = 
models.CharField(max_length=30,default='',null=False)
fac_email = 
models.EmailField(max_length=20,default='',null=False)
fac_password = 
models.SlugField(max_length=15,default='',null=False)
```

also registered the models in admin.py
'`admin.site.register(studentlogin), admin.site.register(facultylogin)`

I need help !!

Comment: Can you add your model code? Looks like you haven't defined your models correctly

Comment: I have added the models code. Is it correct !?

Comment: `facultylogin` does not inherit from `models.Model`

Comment: Oh Okay , but is this the right way to go ? (like without creating an app) also what can I do to fix this !?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up sqlite3 in the same file that you have `INSTALLED_APPS` by using the `DATABASES = {}` setting

For example:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

[Example](https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangodatabase.html)

Might be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762878/sqlite-3-database-with-django)

[Example2](https://python.plainenglish.io/connect-django-with-database-43f1965565e0)

Comment: Actually I have already done this , but still I am getting this error ' TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable'